# Java Methode naming Convention getX

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Let's say I have a class rectangle with the two Attributes: "length" and "width".
Also, it has a method to calculate the Area that returns the product of length * width. Is it a good style to call the method getArea? I am not sure because there is no attribute area, on the other hand a rectangle always has an area.
So in such cases should I use a name like calculate area or getArea?

Comment: It's for sure not "calculate area" with a space. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Naming your method `getArea` is okay.

Although it's not an attribute of the class, it is indeed a calculated property, that can be seen as something similar to an attribute, but not stored in the actual object.

Furthermore, you can declare an actual attribute `area` and keep it in sync with the other attributes for your objects. It's not recommended though, cause it's easier, and sometimes cleaner, to maintain your code with calculated properties.

Note that on the client side, there would be no difference between `getWidth()` and `getArea()` methods (in regards of which one has direct access to a certain attribute), since client shouldn't be able to know the internal structure of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Getters are among other things there to hide the inner implementation from a caller from outside. The caller does not need to know how an object inside works. This also makes it easier to change the implementation later on.
An implementation of a rectangle could consist of only one attribute `area` which is accessed via a `getArea()` getter. But later on it could be calculated from `length` and `width` without the caller noticing a change or even having to adapt his code.